# Android How to return default fragment after several moments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working with several tab , and inside each tab ,
I use fragments to change pages

such as

```
Fragment fragment = new Personal_selectapp();
                    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);     
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);  
                    transaction.commit();
```

while I found some problems ,

1. sometimes i press back button it will crash ,  can I just override
   the function again? or is there any better way to solve it ?
2. when i am in Tab1 ,I clicked and to the subpage (ex tab1-1 ->tab1-2)
   then I click tab2 , when I go back to tab1 , It still in tab1-2 page,
   but i want to back to tab1-1 ,

how to do this ?

Tab1      | Tab2

tab1-1    |  tab2-1

tab1-2    |  tab2-2

edit ********************
I override the mainfragment :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    return true;
}
```

like this . 
as a result , when I visit fragments, they will be put into a stack so that I can press "back"to go back to last page ,
the problem is , I need each tab start from it's homepage when clicked,
but in this condition , they stopped in the last page I clicked , that is not what I want . I need they go to the right  page when tab is clicked .

Comment: Your problem is quite confusing, can you please ellaborate this?

Comment: let's fix the bigger one , 
I override the back button function in the mainfragment ,where I set my tab

Comment: solved it or not yet?

Comment: I solved it by know what the tabid is  ,though i think there must be a better solution :)